# SharePoint 2013 - Search for Specific Words Inside Documents

Tags: search, sharepoint-server

I have a set of pdf, word and excel documents inside a document set. There are multiple document sets available and when i use the default OOTB search functionality and search within the document set, the results are displayed as expected.

For example, if i search for the word "SharePoint" then all documents that have the word SharePoint is getting displayed properly. Now what i require is to find how many times the word "SharePoint" is found in each of the document within all the files that are present in the document set.

I tried using the **KeywordQuery** and **SearchExecutor** class but it returns the same results as I see in the default search but what I require is the word frequency count in each document.

**Example**: DocumentA.pdf – SharePoint (10)
DocumentB.pdf – SharePoint (5)

Is there any API available in SharePoint 2013 that could help me to achieve this? Does SharePoint even performs this? or does it stops searching in a file when it first encounters the word?

When I search for something does SharePoint search inside the list of indexed files every time? If yes how does it work under the hood and is there a way that I can perform the same?

Any pointers or code snippets would be highly helpful.